# Redirecting to previous page after authentication in node.js using passport.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, redirect, express, passport.js

I'm trying to establish a login mechanism using node.js, express and passport.js. The Login itself works quite nice, also sessions are stored nicely with redis but I do have some troubles with redirecting the user to where he started from before being prompted to authenticate.

e.g. User follows link `http://localhost:3000/hidden` is then redirected to `http://localhost:3000/login` but then I want him to be redirected again back to `http://localhost:3000/hidden`.

The purpose of this is, if the user access randomly a page he needs to be logged in first, he shall be redirected to the /login site providing his credentials and then being redirected back to the site he previously tried to access.

Here is my login post

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err)
        } else if (!user) { 
            console.log('message: ' + info.message);
            return res.redirect('/login') 
        } else {
            req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                return next(); // <-? Is this line right?
            });
        }
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

and here my ensureAuthenticated Method

```
function ensureAuthenticated (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { 
      return next();
  }
  res.redirect('/login');
}
```

which hooks into the `/hidden` page

```
app.get('/hidden', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    res.render('hidden', { title: 'hidden page' });
});
```

The html output for the login site is quite simple

```html
<form method="post" action="/login">

  <div id="username">
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text" value="bob" name="username">
  </div>

  <div id="password">
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" value="secret" name="password">
  </div>

  <div id="info"></div>
    <div id="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Hi I am also doing the same the only difference is when user is successfully log in then i will redirect to welcome.html page with message like'Welcome UserName'. hear UserName will be his/her LoginName. Can you show me how to pass text box value to next page ??

Comment: not knowing much I'd guess simply pass it through. According from my example that might be:
res.render('hidden', {title: 'hidden page', username: 'Tyrion Lannister'});

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I don't know about passport, but here's how I do it:

I have a middleware I use with `app.get('/account', auth.restrict, routes.account)` that sets `redirectTo` in the session...then I redirect to /login

```
auth.restrict = function(req, res, next){
    if (!req.session.userid) {
        req.session.redirectTo = '/account';
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        next();
    }
};
```

Then in `routes.login.post` I do the following:

```
var redirectTo = req.session.redirectTo || '/';
delete req.session.redirectTo;
// is authenticated ?
res.redirect(redirectTo);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Aren't you setting the redirect /account direct in your code? What happens if you have another link let's say /pro_accounts using the same auth.restrict they would be redirected to /account ....

Comment: That's true. I always redirect to /account after they login, but you could replace it with `req.session.redirect_to = req.path`

Comment: hm.. its not quite I'm looking for. 
I call ensureAuthenticated to figure out if a user is already authed or not, if not it is redirected to /login. From this view I need a way to get back to /account. Calling req.path within /login gives me simple /login back. Using referer doesn't work either plus its not quite certain if the browser sets the referer properly...

Comment: You need to set `req.session.redirect_to = req.path` inside your auth middleware. Then read it and delete it in `login.post` route.

Comment: this isn't a great solution for passport which accepts successRedirect as an option at a point that request isn't available

Comment: or you can use req.flash('redirect')

Comment: BUG: user wants to go to /account but he is not authorized, he is redirected to login and session.redirectTo='/account'.

Then he goes to '/' and logins through main page, but session.redirectTo still equals '/account' and he redirects to account but should not

Answer (score 126):

In your `ensureAuthenticated` method save the return url in the session like this:

```
...
req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl; 
res.redirect('/login');
...
```

Then you can update your passport.authenticate route to something like:

```
app.get('/auth/google/return', passport.authenticate('google'), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(req.session.returnTo || '/');
    delete req.session.returnTo;
});
```

Comment: Worked on the first pass, but I needed to add the following after the redirect in the passport.authenticate route to avoid being taken back to the returnTo address after subsequent logout/login:
`req.session.returnTo = null;`
See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758207/why-is-passportjs-in-node-not-removing-session-on-logout) for additional info about passport's default logout, which, on examination of source, seems to only clear the session.user, and not the entire session.

Comment: can i simply pass around a query like ?callback=/profile instead of session

Comment: @OMGPOP  you probably could, but that doesn't sound very secure, is there a reason you don't want to take advantage of the session?

Comment: @linuxdan not at all. but it's just troublesome to extract the redirect link out and put into session, then when user redirect back, assign back the redirect link from the session

Comment: @linuxdan why is it insecure?

Comment: @phillipwei - if you are passing around authentication related data on the query string, you are giving hackers implementation details of your authentication system.

Comment: @linuxdan but the value here is just the url that the user navigated to originally; I don't think that needs securing does it -- or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @phillipwei I'm not a security expert, so I can't say for sure, but when it comes to authentication I try to err on the side of caution. Session variables are generally more secure than url parameters since they aren't passed around in the open where a simple packet sniffer can pick them up. Is the redirect path an asset worth securing? Maybe not, but I could imagine it being a problem when combined with other possible security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Instead of `req.path` I would use `req.originalUrl` since it is a combination of baseUrl and path, see [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.originalUrl)

Comment: need to move the delete line to above the other line, but works otherwise

Comment: URLs are not passed in the clear if the site is secured with TLS.  And if your site isn't secured with TLS, most OAuth implementations aren't secure either, so it's a non-issue.  On the other hand, I have not been able to find a way to pass along a callback URL to Google that Google will return when it comes back.

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at [connect-ensure-login](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login), which works along side Passport to do exactly what you want!

Answer (score 7):

My way of doing things:

```
const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next()
  }
  res.redirect( `/login?origin=${req.originalUrl}` )
};
```

**GET /login** controller:

```
if( req.query.origin )
  req.session.returnTo = req.query.origin
else
  req.session.returnTo = req.header('Referer')

res.render('account/login')
```

**POST /login** controller:

```
  let returnTo = '/'
  if (req.session.returnTo) {
    returnTo = req.session.returnTo
    delete req.session.returnTo
  }

  res.redirect(returnTo);
```

**POST /logout** controller (not sure if there is 100% ok, comments are welcome):

```
req.logout();
res.redirect(req.header('Referer') || '/');
if (req.session.returnTo) {
  delete req.session.returnTo
}
```

**Clear returnTo middleware** (clears returnTo from session on any route except auth routes - for me they are /login and /auth/:provider ):

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(needle)
{
  return(this.indexOf(needle) == 0)
}

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if ( !(req.path == '/login' || req.path.startsWith('/auth/')) && req.session.returnTo) {
    delete req.session.returnTo
  }
  next()
})
```

This approach have **two features**:

- you can protect some routes with *isAuthenticated* middleware;
- *on any page* you can simply click on login URL, and after login *return* to that page;

Comment: There were so many good response here, I was able to use your example and made it work with my project. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using [connect-ensure-login](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login) there is a super-easy, integrated way to do this with Passport using the `successReturnToOrRedirect` parameter. When used, passport will send you back to the originally requested URL or fallback to the URL you provide.

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successReturnToOrRedirect: '/user/me',
  failureRedirect: '/user/login',
  failureFlash: true
}));
```

https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login#log-in-and-return-to

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of @jaredhanson's answer

Comment: Worth adding that `express-session` needs to be configured so that is saves 'uninitialized' cookies: `{ saveUninitialized: true }`. This means that anonymous users will have sessions created for them, and put more pressure against your session store. On the upside, these sessions will store the `returnTo` location and be used after an anonymous user authenticates successfully.

Answer (score 1):

@chovy and @linuxdan answers have **bug** with not clearing `session.returnTo` if user goes to another page after login redirect (thats doesn't require authentication) and logins through there. So add this code to their implementations:

```
// clear session.returnTo if user goes to another page after redirect to login
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.path != '/login' && req.session.returnTo) {
        delete req.session.returnTo
    }
    next()
})
```

If you do some ajax requests from login page, you can also exclude them.

---

Another approach is to use **flash** in `ensureAuthenticated`

```
req.flash('redirectTo', req.path)
res.redirect('/login')
```

And then in GET login

```
res.render('login', { redirectTo: req.flash('redirectTo') })
```

In view add hidden field to login form (example in jade)

```
if (redirectTo != '')
    input(type="hidden" name="redirectTo" value="#{redirectTo}")
```

In POST login

```
res.redirect(req.body.redirectTo || '/')
```

Notice that redirectTo will clear after first GET login with it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest (and properly) way to achieve this is [setting `failureRedirect` and `successRedirect` options](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate#redirects).

Comment: Can you elaborate? I can see `successRedirect` being used on the return route, but then the intended destination (i.e. `returnTo` above) would be lost, right?