# Redirect to original page with passportjs-google after auth (without sessions)

Tags: express, google-oauth, passport.js

I'm writing a site whose content should not be accessed unless the user has logged in via Google (and their email is in a hardcoded list).  PassportJS makes this easy, with a middleware like

```
app.all '*', (req, res, next) ->
    if req.isAuthenticated()
        next()
    else
        passport.authenticate('google')(req, res, next)
```

If the user is not authenticated, they're kicked over to Google for auth-- so far so good.  When Google auths the user, it sends them to my return url:

```
app.get '/auth/google/return', passport.authenticate('google',
    successRedirect: '/'
    failureRedirect: '/login'
)
```

However, I don't want to send my user back to `/`, I want to send them to the original url they were trying to visit.

How do I use passportjs/passport-google to redirect my user to the page they were originally trying to visit when my middleware caught that they were unauthenticated and kicked them over to Google?

I've seen some suggestions of using session state, but I don't want to do that because it's janky-- I'd imagine if the user opens multiple tabs to the site and is asked for login on each, all the tabs would end up directed to the url the last one was trying to go to.

Is there a way to do this without sessions?

Answer (score 1):

you can store the current url (`req.originalUrl`) in `req.session`, and redirect users by passport.js strategy to url of `/auth/success`. And `/auth/success` redirects to last page.
I can't find out a version, that do not use sessions for this.

```
app.get('/auth/success', function(request, response) {
  response.redirect(request.session.lastUrl || '/');
});

app.get('/auth/google/return', passport.authenticate('google', {
    successRedirect: '/auth/success'
    failureRedirect: '/login'}
));

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    req.session.lastUrl = req.originalUrl;
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        next()
    } else {
        passport.authenticate('google')(req, res, next);
    }
});
```

Comment: I specifically don't want to use sessions

Comment: passport.js use sessions, so probably you have to use it. If you are afraid, that session storage can be a the single point of failure, you can use session storage by encrypted cookies http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieSession.html

Comment: Sessions are fine for what passportjs uses them for: saving login state, which is fundamentally an attribute of the user's session.  Using sessions to figure out where to route a user is an antipattern, because it adds state when the entirety of the routing should be encapsulated in the url.  We can also see that it fails if the user's browser cookies are not present or have been disabled, or in my earlier example where the user has multiple tabs open to the website, each for a different url and each requesting login.

Comment: Can't you have Google redirect your users to the original URL and do the check (whether it failed or succeeded) there ?

Or can't you include the original URL when kicking users to Google in a query parameter ? (I think Google OAuth has a "state" parameter you could use for that)

Comment: To add to Jared's comment - session storage fails when working with multiple tabs with multiple URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider using query params for URLs as storage for redirect path, like redirect( `/login?origin=${req.path}` ) or, maybe, specify them in successRedirect.

Also examine this answer: [Redirecting to previous page after authentication in node.js using passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335881/redirecting-to-previous-page-after-authentication-in-node-js-using-passport-js/38456209#38456209) . Maybe it can be helpful.