# Redirect to previous page using passport.js facebook strategy in express

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, authentication, passport.js

This question have been posted before, [but somehow the given recommendations don't work form me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335881/redirecting-to-previous-page-after-authentication-in-node-js-using-passport-js). Am stuck on this and not sure how to proceed.

I can't redirect the user back after its authentication. I'm using the recommended '**successReturnToOrRedirect**' property, but it keeps sending it back to '/'. I have checked **req.session.returnTo** and **req.path** and both of them have  '/' as value, even though I'm calling /auth/facebook from a different page.

Here's my code:

```
 router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends']}));

router.get('/auth/facebook/callback', 

      passport.authenticate('facebook', { successReturnToOrRedirect: '/',
                                          failureRedirect: '/' })

    );
```

```
    <a href="/auth/facebook"> <div class="fb-button-login">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Continuar con <strong> facebook</strong>
        </div> </a>
```

Comment: I'm also having the same problem, `req.headers.referer` isn't present after the callback url gets called, so not sure what to do https://imgur.com/a/GEhL3