# Redirect to previous page using googleOauth and passport

Tags: node.js, api, routes, google-oauth, passport.js

I am creating a nodejs api that uses passport and google oauth. I want to redirect users original link they came from. However, in my login route, the "console.log" is never reached. How do I record the originalUrl in an api like this?

I've been trying to follow along of this: [Redirecting to previous page after authentication in node.js using passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335881/redirecting-to-previous-page-after-authentication-in-node-js-using-passport-js) but am stuck.

````
router.get("/login", passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["profile","email"]
}),function(req,res){
    console.log(req.originalUrl) //never got to here

    res.send(req.user)
})

router.get('/redirect',passport.authenticate('google'),function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.originalUrl)//gives a long URL string from google's auth
        res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/");//I want to redirect to where the user came from rather than just localhost 3000
        // res.send(req.user)
    }
);```
````